# AngularJS $http cause twice request?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my JS

```
var rentalkika = angular.module('rentalkika', ['ngRoute']);
rentalkika.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/main.html' 
    })
    .when('/sewa_mobil', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/sewa_mobil.html',
        controller : 'FilterController' 
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
        controller : 'ContactController'
    })
    .when('/register', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/register.html'
    });

});

rentalkika.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, $http) {
    var config = {
        headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id' : 'secret' }    
    };


    $http.get('http://128.199.249.233:1337/parse/classes/vehicle', config).then(function (response){
        console.log(response.data.results);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(response);
    });


});
```

Here is my `contact.html`

```
<div>
tes about html
</div>
```

When I go to `localhost:3000/#/contact` then inspect chrome in network section, it show twice request on `http://128.199.249.233:1337/parse/classes/vehicle` the first return `200` response and second return `304`.

Here is my `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Koupon - Index</title>
    <!-- meta info -->
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Koupon HTML5 Template" />
    <meta name="description" content="Koupon - Premiun HTML5 Template for Coupons Website">
    <meta name="author" content="Dark Cyber" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <!-- <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <!-- <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <!-- Bootstrap styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boostrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boostrap_responsive.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome styles (icons) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font_awesome.css">
    <!-- Main Template styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <!-- IE 8 Fallback -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

    <!-- Your custom styles (blank file) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="rentalkika">





    <!-- //////////////////////////////////
//////////////MAIN HEADER///////////// 
////////////////////////////////////-->
    <header class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo-small.png" alt="logo" title="logo" class="logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                    <!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->
                    <div class="flexnav-menu-button" id="flexnav-menu-button">Menu</div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills flexnav" id="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800">
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Layanan</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#sewa_mobil">Sewa Mobil</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Shuttle</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="features-typography.html">Paket Wisata</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="blog-sidebar-right.html">Blog</a>
                            </li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tertarik menjadi mitra kami?</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- END MAIN NAVIGATION -->
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <!-- LOGIN REGISTER LINKS -->
                    <ul class="login-register">
                        <li><a class="popup-text" href="#login-dialog" data-effect="mfp-move-from-top"><i class="icon-signin"></i>Sign in</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#register"><i class="icon-edit"></i>Sign up</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- LOGIN REGISTER LINKS CONTENT -->
    <div id="login-dialog" class="mfp-with-anim mfp-hide mfp-dialog clearfix">
        <i class="icon-signin dialog-icon"></i>
        <h3>Member Login</h3>
        <h5>Welcome back, friend. Login to get started</h5>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <form class="dialog-form">
                <label>E-mail</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="email@domain.com" class="span12">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="My secret password" class="span12">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox">Remember me
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
        <ul class="dialog-alt-links">
            <li><a class="popup-text" href="#register-dialog" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out">Not member yet</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="popup-text" href="#password-recover-dialog" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out">Forgot password</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="password-recover-dialog" class="mfp-with-anim mfp-hide mfp-dialog clearfix">
        <i class="icon-retweet dialog-icon"></i>
        <h3>Password Recovery</h3>
        <h5>Fortgot your password? Don't worry we can deal with it</h5>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <form class="dialog-form">
                <label>E-mail</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="email@domain.com" class="span12">
                <input type="submit" value="Request new password" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END LOGIN REGISTER LINKS CONTENT -->
    
    <!-- //////////////////////////////////
//////////////END MAIN HEADER////////// 
////////////////////////////////////-->


<!-- //// START PAGE CONTENT -->

 <div ng-view>
    
   </div>

<!-- END PAGE CONTENT /// -->



    <!-- //////////////////////////////////
//////////////MAIN FOOTER////////////// 
////////////////////////////////////-->

    <footer class="main">
        <div class="footer-top-area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row row-wrap">
                    <div class="span3">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" title="logo" class="logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <h5>Get it Anywhere</h5>
                        <p>Ultrices varius semper laoreet molestie purus euismod fames odio volutpat eleifend turpis nec cras quam litora dignissim curae lacus platea sociis mauris hendrerit sed fringilla dignissim cum mi amet orci</p>
                        <ul class="list list-app-download">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="icon-windows box-icon" title="Get Windows Phone App" data-toggle="tooltip"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="icon-apple box-icon" title="Get iPhone App" data-toggle="tooltip"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="icon-android box-icon" title="Get Android App" data-toggle="tooltip"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <h5>Koupon on Twitter</h5>
                        <!-- START TWITTER -->
                        <div class="twitter-ticker" id="twitter-ticker"></div>
                        <!-- END TWITTER -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <h5>Recent News</h5>
                        <ul class="list post-list">
                            <li class="post-thumb">
                                <h5 class="title"><a href="#">Gravida porttitor vulputate</a></h5><small>05 August, 2013</small>
                                <p class="post-desciption">Dignissim phasellus magnis mus duis nisl ut lacus vehicula velit</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="post-thumb">
                                <h5 class="title"><a href="#">A duis</a></h5><small>29 July, 2013</small>
                                <p class="post-desciption">Class augue curae accumsan tempor semper id integer adipiscing mattis</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-wrap">
                <div class="span3">
                    <h5>About Koupon</h5>
                    <p>Tellus auctor sem sociosqu cras cursus vitae erat aliquam adipiscing iaculis suscipit curabitur hac hac congue netus integer ridiculus volutpat varius suspendisse velit venenatis facilisi velit quis volutpat enim ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <h5>Company</h5>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Press</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Investors</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <h5>For Business</h5>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li><a href="#">Advertising</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Runnig a Deal</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Accept Payments</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Referral Program</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Developers/API</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Merchant Terms</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <h5>Get Help</h5>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Customer Support</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Return Policy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms Of Use</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Statement</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <h5>Keep in touch</h5>
                    <p>Mauris mus tortor leo augue non sociosqu ridiculus sagittis odio</p>
                    <ul class="list list-social">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-facebook box-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Facebook"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-twitter box-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Twitter"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-flickr box-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Flickr"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-linkedin box-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Linkedin"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-tumblr box-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tumblr"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- //////////////////////////////////
//////////////END MAIN  FOOTER///////// 
////////////////////////////////////-->

    <!-- Scripts queries -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/boostrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/nivo_slider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/countdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flexnav.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/magnific.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tweet.min.js"></script>
     
  <!--   
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    -->
    
    <script src="js/gmap3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wilto_slider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mediaelement.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fitvids.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mail.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  
    <!-- Custom scripts -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Is something wrong or missing with my code?

Comment: Is perhaps the first request an OPTIONS request? An OPTIONS request is made when CORS is in use.

Comment: Are you getting the response? If the api call is made to a different server, you will see TWO request with OPTIONS with 200 response and GET method (in this case) which is normal.

Comment: Return response 200 means success, 304 means that the URL is being re-directed. I recommend sticking a "debugger" in your controller above the http request - and then open the link with developer tools activated, this will tell you whether the controller is being instantiated twice.

Comment: RwamDev yes the first is OPTIONS second is GET.
PaulsonPeter yes I get the response.

Comment: Well played @RwamDev :{D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first request is propably an OPTIONS request or a so called [Preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) which is made when CORS is in use. A preflight request is made to check if the cross site request is safe.